# Restarting hanging threads

Tags: python, multithreading, restart

I have a script that runs but it has a tendency of hanging. I am trying to make another script to run it using threads, but the auto-restarting function does not seem to be working.

What I want this script to do is to restart the function every 900 seconds, or if it is possible, restart it whenever it hangs.

```
import time
import threading
import os

import functionname


def restart():
    time.sleep(900)
    os.execl('currentfilepath')

def res():
    while True:
        try:
            # do your works
            t = threading.Thread(target=restart, args=(), name='reset')
            t.start()
            functionname()
        except:
            print('error')
        finally:
            print('done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res()
```

Comment: why would you want to do this?  wouldn't it be better to fix the scripts that hang?  this just seems to be compounding failure modes, what if the script you call gets interrupted at a sensitive point?

Comment: I am not sure why exactly it is hanging as it only does it sometimes. Besides I am working on a tight deadline so I think this is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I managed to find a way to solve this.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

t=600 #  time to wait

def bar():
    # do stuff


def barn():
    for i in range(t*500):  # runs for 500 times
        # print ("Tick"+str(i)+'n') # just for tracking progress
        time.sleep(1)
        if i % t == 0:
            print('restarting')
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar)
            p.terminate
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar)
            p.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar)
    p.start()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=barn)
    p1.start()
```

Probably not the most elegant but hey, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer works but it seems to be a one shot; on my system it stops running after 1 time. I changed the code to use a while loop instead; now it's working on my system:

```
def barn():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar)
    p.start()
    i = 0
    while(t > i):
        print("running for " + str(i))
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if i == t:
            print('restarting')
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar)
            p.terminate
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar)
            p.start()
            i = 0
```